# "Unable to locate package" only inside a docker image

Tags: php, ubuntu, docker, apt

When I try to install APC inside my docker image with

```
apt-get update && apt-get install php-apcu
```

I get the message :

```
Unable to locate package php-apcu
```

But in my local machine the installation works perfectly. Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the universe repository:

```
RUN apt-get update &&\
 apt-get install -y software-properties-common &&\
 add-apt-repository universe &&\
 apt-get install -y php-apcu
```

If you get a "Error: 'universe' invalid" then you need to use the full source line:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"
```

instead of "universe" in your `apt-add-repository` line.

Comment: I get this error when I try to add universe repository : "Error: 'universe' invalid"